# Dynamically loaded test scripts disrupts test execution order

Tags: unit-testing, qunit

I'm running a set of QUnit tests that use module level `setup` and `teardown` methods. I've noticed that using `start()` and `stop()` inside my tests appears to disrupt when these get called, which causes problems as certain items made available in my setup are not available to some tests that run.

*Edit*: I've noticed that this happens exclusively when I load my test scripts programmatically (I'm using a script loader: [LABjs](http://labjs.com/)). I have modified the subject and content of this question accordingly. I am loading tests like this:

```
$LAB.script('/static/tests.js')
```

Still not sure why this happens.

Here's a sample of my test module:

```
module('Class Foo', {
  setup: function() {
    console.log('setup called');
  },
  teardown: function() {
    console.log('teardown called');
  }
});

test('Test1', function() {
  stop();
  console.log('test1');
  ok(true);
  start();
});

test('Test2', function() {
  stop();
  console.log('test2');
  ok(true);
  start();
});

test('Test3', function() {
  stop();
  console.log('test3');
  ok(true);
  start();
});
```

This yields the console output (note that setup is called twice, then not again):

```
setup called
test1
teardown called
(2)setup called
test3
teardown called
test2
teardown called
```

Remove the start/stop, or modifying my test files to not be loaded programatically (i.e.: using traditional  tags):

```
test('Test3', function() {
  console.log('test3');
  ok(true);
});
```

Yields a more expected order of execution:

```
setup called
test1
teardown called
setup called
test2
teardown called
setup called
test3
teardown called
```

Am I misunderstanding something about how this should be functioning?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Uu6Nw/ - i can't reproduce your issue. but you could try to use asyncTest() instead of test() without the stop() commands

Comment: Thanks @FelixEbert i thought this might have been a version thing (i'm on 1.5.0) but have confirmed that what you see is correct even with the older version; this appears to be something else wrong with the setup. As noted in my edited post, I experience this issue when tests are programmatically loaded to my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that QUnit likes your test scripts to be loaded when it kicks itself off. This action is configurable, so I found the following setup worked to defer QUnit starting until all test scripts were available:

```
QUnit.config.autostart = false;
$LAB.script('/static/tests.js').wait(function() {
  QUnit.start();
});
```

I'm still not sure *why* this happens so would be interested to see any answers in that regard (or I'll update this when I figure it out!) but this solution gets me by for now.